# How to hide an image and pass to another class?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent

I want to hide an image and pass  to another class, but fail to do so.

Activity Flow : From A to B then C. Return values and image from C to B then A.

Next, A can pass data  to B for edit.

**Activity A** (Before)

```
     c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { pass to B
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
              if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               if (name.equals("Project")) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Project1.class);
                                                 Global.img = null;
               v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
               View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
               v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
               v.buildDrawingCache(true);
               intent.putExtra("name", name);
               intent.putExtra("result", result);
               intent.putExtra("description", description);
               intent.putExtra("k", k);
               if (v.getDrawingCache() != null) {
               Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
               if (bitmap == null) {
               Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                                     }
                Global.img = bitmap;

                intent.putExtra("bitmap",true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                                          }
                                             }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  //receive from B
         k = data.getIntExtra("k", 0);
       Log.e("TAG",k+"");
        if (k == 1) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    description=data.getStringExtra("c");
                    if (Global.img != null) {
                        v.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // display image
                    }

                     as=Long.parseLong(result);
                    c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;
}
```

[image]

**Activity B**
[image]

The above code working fine. But what I trying to achieve is I don't want image display on activity A(which is beside the amount).I want image display only when it goes to B.

So here are what I've tried so far. I removed

```
the imageView from `a.xml`
```

also remove

```
if (Global.img != null) {
                        v.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
                    }
```

in activity A **onActivityResult** and run the app.

> 11-13 16:07:15.916  29329-29329/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 29329
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.project.project.Claims$6.onClick(Claims.java:149)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)

where **Claims.java:149** refer to    `if (v.getDrawingCache() != null) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revert your ImageView in xml file and add this xml attribute: `android:visibility="gone"` or `android:visibility="invisible"` to your ImageView

**How to hide an image?** Use xml attribute: `android:visibility="gone"` or `android:visibility="invisible"`